# Python byte buffer object?

Tags: python, buffer

Is there a byte buffer object in Python to which I can append values of specific types? *(preferably with specifiable endianess)*

For example:

```
buf.add_int(4)    # should add a 4 byte integer
buf.add_short(10) # should add a 2 byte short
buf.add_byte(24)  # should add a byte
```

I know that I could just use `struct.pack` but this approach just seems easier. Ideally it should be like the `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` objects in **Java** which do this exact task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can always use [bitstring](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/). It is capable of doing all the things you ask and more.

```
>>> import bitstring
>>> stream=bitstring.BitStream()
>>> stream.append("int:32=4")
>>> stream.append("int:16=10")
>>> stream.append("int:8=24")
>>> stream
BitStream('0x00000004000a18')
>>> stream.bytes
'\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\n\x18'
```

Here is a link to the [documentation](http://packages.python.org/bitstring/#documentation).

Answer (score 5):

As Kark Knechtel suggests you'll have to make your own type that handles this. Here's a quick extension of bytearray:

```
import struct

class DataStream(bytearray):

    def append(self, v, fmt='>B'):
        self.extend(struct.pack(fmt, v))

>>> x = DataStream()
>>> x.append(5)
>>> x
bytearray(b'\x05')
>>> x.append(-1, '>i')
>>> x
bytearray(b'\x05\xff\xff\xff\xff')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap up the `struct.pack` logic in your own class.